# visual studio 2019 installing on non supported OS

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019

I'm looking for solution to install Visual studio 2019 on windows 8 (without any updates i.e. 8.1 update)

1. I was trying to mod installer *.exe file without any luck
2. I read about "manifests" with can contain OS version limitations, but I didn't found any in the offline distributive directory.

Any ideas how can I mod and run VS2019 on windows 8?

Update with more details:

I need "Desktop development with c++" option, so i uploaded installer with code

"vs_community.exe --layout c:\vslayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --includeRecommended --lang en-US"   (on windows 8.1 machine, if it matter).

Later i move this offline cache to windows 8 machine, run "setup.exe" and get incompatibility error.

Answer (score 0):

[This URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/compatibility) explains the compatibility of Visual Studio 2019 and apparently, there should not be any problem. What do you expect to lack, as mentioned in your first question?

Comment: There was a typo in word "luck". sorry   i mean when i start setup.exe, installer said, that Windows 8 is no longer supported and you must update to windows 8.1, but i need to install it on clean Windows 8